# Earth Engine: combining reducers does not give same output as running reducers separately?

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

I am trying to combine reducers, which according to my understanding, is running parallel yet independent reducers when using `sharedInputs: true` (see [doc](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_intro#combining-reducers)). But actually, I notice that **with `combine()`, the output is different than compared to running each reducer separately**. Is this a bug, or I did not understand properly the `combine()` operation?

For the example, I simply re-run the EE example on [weighted reducers](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_weighting), which compares the output of weighted sums versus non-weighted sums. Now I just do the same thing, but combining those. We get:

- Separate reducers:

  - weighted: -9079.394626741121
  - unweighted: -9086.503929115412
- Combined reducers:

  - weighted: **-9438.194106051067**
  - unweighted: -9079.394626741121

What is going on? Why does combining reducers not give the same output as running them separately?

#### Code

Link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8a4fffe6b446f908d6f1db5b33304048

```
// First lines are exactly from: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_weighting

var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_044034_20140318');

// Creat an arbitrary region.
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.496, 37.532, -121.554, 37.538);

// Make an NDWI image.  It will have one band named 'nd'.
var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']);

// Compute the weighted mean of the NDWI image clipped to the region.
var weighted = ndwi.clip(geometry)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30})
  .get('nd');

// Compute the UN-weighted mean of the NDWI image clipped to the region.
var unweighted = ndwi.clip(geometry)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30})
  .get('nd');

/// New code combining reducers  
var weighted_unw = ndwi.clip(geometry)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().combine({
      reducer2: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted(),
      outputPrefix: "weighted",
      sharedInputs: true
    }),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30});

var unwweighted_w = ndwi.clip(geometry)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted().combine({
      reducer2: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      outputPrefix: "weighted",
      sharedInputs: true
    }),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30});



// Observe the difference between weighted and unweighted reductions.
print('weighted:', weighted);
print('unweighted', unweighted);

print("weighted_unw", weighted_unw)
print("unwweighted_w", unwweighted_w)
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is a fun error. My guess is that `sharedInputs: true` does not work with `.unweighted`. This is very likely since the inputs should ideally be different, but are not expected to be different. This is also kind of confirmed when you set `sharedInputs: false`.

```
var unwweighted_w = ndwi.clip(geometry)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted().combine({
      reducer2: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      outputPrefix: "weighted",
      sharedInputs: false
    }),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30});
```

You will get this error:

> Reducer.combine: Can't combine  (unweighted inputs) with SUM (weighted inputs).

Still, this isn't expected behaviour. I would try to get help on the [Google Earth Engine Developer Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-earth-engine-developers). There are some very savy users on there. Otherwise a bug report might also be a possibility.

Comment: interestingly, the problem also happens with `sharedInputs: false`, if you add a second identical band. Just add `.addBands(ndwi)` in your code, won't produce a code error, but give erroneous results? But yes, I am gld you confirm this is indeed unexpected result, thanks!