# GEE never count 100% of the pixels

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, count

I have few codes that count number of pixels in different classes in GEE, and then calc the precentage of them using the total number of pixels that were count. The code seems to work, but when I check the results, I find out that it never count all the pixels.
for example, here is the results of raster that has only  3 possible class values- high, mean and low.

If you sum all the count, you don't get to the total count numner (338+598+771 =1707, not 1789), and then ,also when I calc precentage I never get to 100%.

[image]

I believe it's result of the way that GEE works with polygon that on the border (e.g takes only "whole" pixels), but is there any way to change it and to make it count all of the pixels?

My end goal: when I calculate precentage, to get to 100%.

Edit: link to sample code which  has the same problem:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/761d16596d243e9bc0d053fa84fa2c66

Comment: It would be very useful to have the code which generates your output. Otherwise troubleshooting is a lot of guesswork.

Comment: @JonasV I have edited my question and now it has the code

Comment: @Reut You have to make your assets public for us to access them. I don't know if this applies to your case, but you didn't mention the possibility that some of your pixels are NoData. I believe the "polygon-border" cases will be the same method for the individual class counts and the overall count, so I doubt that's the source of the discrepancy (but I'm not sure).

Comment: @JonasV I think now it suppose to be shared, let me know if not. there are not suppose to be pixels with no data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe it's result of the way that GEE works with polygon that on
>   the border (e.g takes only "whole" pixels), but is there any way to
>   change it and to make it count all of the pixels?

You are right about the borders. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_weighting):

> By default, reducers applied to imagery weight the inputs according to
>   the mask value.

You can make a count reducer unweighted by calling `ee.Reducer.count().unweighted()`. There seems to be a [caveat](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357401/earth-engine-combining-reducers-does-not-give-same-output-as-running-reducers-s/357440#357440) when you combine multiple reducers though, so I'd make all of the combined reducers unweighted.

Here's your code with unweighted reducers, and counts/percentages adding up:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/b92700bd7f454ceeaff53306d3d54ac5